# Referencing Images in JS with/out ERB Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am using jquery.flipbook.js, https://gist.github.com/kgn/719686

and the following code is required:

```
$('img.intro').flipbook({
    'start': 0,
    'end': 137,
    'loop': false,
    'fps': 20,
    'mobileStep': 3,
    'images':"/intro_png/intro-png_.%2d.png" 
   // "url(/assets/intro_png/intro-png_%2d)"
});
```

the `%2d` in the above is required to iterate to the next image in a png sequence. I'm not just referencing one file above, but many (138).  Where can I put my intro_png directory with all the PNGS so I can reference it without using ERB code.  If the above is parsed in erb, I believe the `%2d` will lose it's meaning, and rails will most likely just reference one file.

I tried to put them in the public directory in rails, but I still got 138 404s when I tried to load the page.

**Update**: The approach I am using now is the following:

```
    'images':"<%=asset_path('intro_png/intro-png_')%>"+'%2d.png'
```

As you see, I'm trying to concat the ruby part with the js part.  The only problem is ruby code isn't a file until the js is parsed with it, so I get a `Sprockets::FileNotFound` error.  Is there anyway to bypass that error?

Or another work around?

**Edit:**

I'd also be willing to put the files in the PUBLIC directory.
I tried

```
'images':'url("/intro_png/intro-png_%2d.png")'
```

To no avail.  *sigh*

**Update 2**

The library does parse: the 404's look like this:

```
http://localhost:3002/asset-url('/intro-png_134.png') 404 (Not Found)
```

I'd appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: Out of all the things you have tried, the first approach is what appears sensible. Putting the images in the public directory won't involve the asset pipeline and that is good for this case. I would expect the flibook JS to parse your image url and set the appropriate location for the image tags in the HTML it generates. Can you check (and tell us) what are the actual HTTP requests sent that are resulting in 404s? Is the %2d properly being handled by flipbook JS? (Note: I do not know anything about flibook plugin)

Comment: Are you seeing `asset-url(....)` even when you specify just `'images':"/intro_png/intro-png_.%2d.png"` as you initially put in the question? Do you tell the flipbooks plugin somewhere that your back-end is Rails and that the images are served through asset-pipeline? Other that that I do not see why `asset-url` should appear in the final path.

Comment: I do not see asset-url if I don't include it, but it still 404s.  Should it not?  I thought it made sense...

Comment: Specify `'images':"/intro_png/intro-png_.%2d.png"` in your flipbook config. Create a directory named `intro_png` in your public folder. Put all your images `intro-png_1.png` to `intro-png_138.png` in that `intro_png` folder. Now if it still 404s, paste the URL that is resulting in 404. In this setup there is not asset-url anywhere.

Comment: Yep, that's how I have it. It looks like this: http://localhost:3002/intro_png/intro-png_.04.png

Comment: Ahh there was an extra dot -.-

Comment: Cool. I believe it is all good now. A general suggestion, do not use asset pipeline unless you want to manage your assets through Ruby/Rails. And of course absolutely do not use it if you are not sure how the entire asset pipeline works. Read the rails guides on asset pipeline. It is pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
`'images':'asset-url("/intro_png/intro-png_%2d.png")'`

or

`image: = '<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>'` but you need rename your file to file.js.erb

If any of this answers work try to find the solution here: [asset_pipeline](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

**EDITING**:

And trying something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mLv2s/2/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  I tried that, I still get a 404. The path this reads out is:  http://localhost:3002/asset-url(%22/intro_png/intro-png_137.png%22) - I'm no sure what the deal is with all the %22 and stuff

Comment: I don't understand the use of %22

Comment: That must be coming from flipbook.js? Not sure, but that's how the above code is being interpreted

Comment: I just checked, it was because double quotes were inside single quotes.  If I swapped the double with singles, and vice versa. The readout is as follows http://localhost:3002/asset-url('/intro_png/intro-png_137.png') 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I explained why the ERB approach wasn't working above.  Sprockets error. the %2d isn't actually the file name, it needs to be interpreted by the js libs